# Most efficient to append some columns of a data frame to some other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, append

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
foo <- data.frame(a=letters,b=seq(1,26),
                  n1=rnorm(26),n2=rnorm(26),
                  u1=runif(26),u2=runif(26))
```

I want to append columns `u1` and `u2` to columns `n1` and `n2`. For now, I found the following way:

```
df1 <- foo[,c("a","b","n1","n2")]
df2 <- foo[,c("a","b","u1","u2")]
names(df2) <- names(df1)
bar <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

That does the trick. However, it seems a little bit involved. Am I too picky? Or is there a faster/simpler way to do this in R?

Comment: you would probably find what you need by searching for reshaping not appending `reshape(foo, dir = 'long', varying = list(c('n1','u1'), c('n2','u2')))[,c("a","b","n1","n2")]`

Comment: Maybe? `rbind(foo[1:4], setNames(foo[c(1, 2, 5, 6)], names(foo[1:4])))`

Comment: @rawr, I prefer your solution because it uses named columns instead than numbers, thus it leads to more readable code. I tried to read `?reshape`, and here's my understanding of your code: please correct/integrate if needed, so that I can learn.`varying` stores the couples of columns which must be joined. All other columns are duplicated. Since the result of  `reshape` would also contain the duplicated `u1`, `u2` columns, which I don't need, you filter only the required columns with `[,c("a","b","n1","n2")]`. Correct?

Comment: @DeltaIV the `varying` columns are the ones which will be reshaped from wide to long format. all other columns are assumed to be id variables meaning that they will be unchanged and copied as necessary to match the wide-to-long dimensions. `reshape` add some extra columns which are useful for turning the result back into the original format, but since they are not needed here, we just ignore them

Comment: @rawr, your solution is the one I like the most. If you post it as an answer, I'll choose it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `full_join()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = c("a", "b", "n1" = "u1", "n2" = "u2"))
```

From the documentation:

> **full_join**
>
> return all rows and all columns from both x and y. Where
>   there are not matching values, returns NA for the one missing.
>
> **by**
>
> a character vector of variables to join by. If NULL, the default,
>   join will do a natural join, using all variables with common names
>   across the two tables. A message lists the variables so that you can
>   check they're right.
>
> *To join by different variables on x and y use a named vector. For
>   example, by = c("a" = "b") will match x.a to y.b.*

Comment: @Steven Beaupré, it's an interesting option, but it requires to preliminarly split `foo` into `df1` and `df2`. That's not a bad thing - it's what I do now! - but the other solutions don't require this,  thus I'm going with one of them.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe creating `df1` and `df2` is not strictly necessary - one could simply substitute them with `foo[,c("a", "b", "n1", "n2")]` and `foo[,c("a", "b", "u1", "u2")]`, to the expense of readability. Still, the  `reshape` solution seems more readable to me, but that's probably just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: @DeltaIV You could also do something like: `full_join(select(foo, -starts_with("u")), select(foo, -starts_with("n")), by = c("a", "b", "n1" = "u1", "n2" = "u2"))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map()` to concatenate the columns, and `cbind()` with recycling to arrive at the final data frame.

```
cbind(foo[1:2], Map(c, foo[3:4], foo[5:6]))
```

Substitute numerical indexes with column names, if desired.

```
cbind(foo[c("a", "b")], Map(c, foo[c("n1", "n2")], foo[c("u1", "u2")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Short-hand:

```
rbind(foo[1:4], setNames(foo[c(1, 2, 5, 6)], names(foo[1:4])))
```

Long-winded:

```
rbind(foo[c("a", "b", "n1", "n2")], setNames(foo[c("a", "b", "u1", "u2")], c("a", "b", "n1", "n2")))
```

Long-winded (more DRY):

```
nms <- c("a", "b", "n1", "n2")
rbind(foo[nms], setNames(foo[c("a", "b", "u1", "u2")], nms))
```

Comment: I like the DRY solution more because of its readability. I'm surprised that `foo[nms]` works. I always thought that the right call would be `foo[ ,nms]`. Looks like I've always been wrong.